# Display helloworld from mongodb to android application but use of php web service and json

Tags: php, android, json, web-services, mongodb

***Display helloworld from mongodb to android application but use of php web service and json***

I need to parse data from a mongodb collection to android application where i will its can be parsed by json and displayed in the android applcation.

```
<?php
 $connection = new MongoClient();
 $collection = $connection->database->collectionName;

 $document = $collection->findOne();

 echo json_encode($document); 
?>
```

This is the php code for my web service I connects to mongo and finds collection and enchodes it to json. This displays

```
{"_id":{"$id":"52769d23b829444827000000"},"name":"MongoDB","type":"database","count":1,"info":{"x":203,"y":102},"versions":["0.9.7","0.9.8","0.9.9"]}'
```

This is a test collection that I made from a tutorial.

My main question is how to do pull this data to android applcation, such as the name.

I know this is simple but I am a student and I am only learning mongo and android.

What I need to do is create a mongo database will text and display that text in android to prove that they can connect.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are taking on way to much here, using way to many technologies running on way to many locations.

On one hand you have an webservice, running PHP frontend and MongoDB backend. You seem to understand the basics there.

On the other hand.. You have android. Android generally runs on handheld devices.
The program you write for the Android has nothing to do with and shall not mixed with the PHP and MongoDB application you are writing the service as.

All the Android application needs to know is "aha. There is a service. That service provides me with this json when I connect to the internet and request that specific url".

That service then needs to properly protected so a rouge hacker out there can't just sniff out your service and pretend to be a android device and cause the service harm.

I suggest you close this question and submit a new one, simply asking:

- How do I make a web request on Android
- How do I parse a JSON document on Android

I am however certain you will be able to find that answer in any android development tutorial